# OutOfMemoryError while creating XSSFWorkbook in Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, spring-boot, garbage-collection, apache-poi

I have a spring boot Rest service which i am using to create excel file(xlsm). Getting strange issue as application start first time it will easily create a excel file but calling a rest endpoint again generate OutOfMemoryError exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cur$CurLoadContext.attr(Cur.java:3044)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cur$CurLoadContext.attr(Cur.java:3065)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxHandler.startElement(Locale.java:3198)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:498)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:180)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:275)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1653)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:324)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:890)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:813)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:108)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1198)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:564)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.load(Locale.java:3414)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1272)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1259)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderBase.parse(SchemaTypeLoaderBase.java:345)
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.WorksheetDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.read(XSSFSheet.java:228)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.onDocumentRead(XSSFSheet.java:220)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.parseSheet(XSSFWorkbook.java:452)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.onDocumentRead(XSSFWorkbook.java:417)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:184)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:286)
    at com.service.ExcelReportManager.runReport(ExcelReportManager.java:248)
    at com.report.controller.ReportingEndPoint.runReport(ReportingEndPoint.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
```

Here is a code which creating this exception:

```
try (OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(fileCopy);
             XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg))
```

as i am closing a resource but still there is somehow creating problem. I read different already created issue here but nothing seems to be working for me. Is there any clue to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Is the excel file size too big?

If it is, it can be causing this error, the memory use for generating and reading big excel files with poi is very high.

Your try syntax is correct, the resources will always be closed.

You can give a try on increasing the max memory for the execution jvm.
Use `-Xmx2048m` on initialization, for example.

Comment: i agree with you that might be poi limitation but after generating excel sheet once why not all resources cleanup by POI and initialize as fresh in new rest call? I double check my code line by line and dont see where i missed to close resources. increase a memory is also not a solution as i am testing and facing this on my dev environment and when i deploy on production this mean i need to keep in my mind that this particular process is memoray eater. Is there any other library rather than POI which can help me?

Comment: That exception message says that is occurring a GC overhead, what means that GC is trying to free memory but is unable to get the job done. I suggest that you do some GC optimization on the code. For example, inside loops where you deal with rows and cells, try setting them to null after use of the variables, this can give a signal for GC to run over these objects. See this https://www.baeldung.com/java-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded

Comment: Ok nice idea, let me try this tomorrow and will let you know. By the way i try to call garbage collection by code at the end of process but it not guaranteed that jvm do it or not.

Comment: @NatanaelVeloso the message “GC overhead limit exceeded” implies that the garbage collector *can* free some memory, but it’s so little, that it has to run again only a few CPU cycles later, so the application spends more than 98% of its time in garbage collection. Practically, the difference to an ordinary `OutOfMemoryError` is just this small amount of memory that could be freed, so the solutions to both are the same. Try with more memory or, in case of POI, refactor the application to use POI’s streaming API when possible. Otherwise, POI’s ooxml handling needs tons of memory, unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you @Holger!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of XSSFWorkbook (which keeps the entire Excel workbook in memory) try to use very efficient and high performance streaming SXSSFWorkbook class like below:

```
SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(100);
```

where 100 is the default number of rows that will be kept in memory and processed in real time.